# Return value of Event::getAttendees() must be an instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage, null returned

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have an issue with my Extbase model and the usage of ObjectStorage.
I have an object in database, which doesn't contain any Attendees.
On editing and saving the object via `$repository->update($object);`, I get the following error:

```
Return value of TheCodingOwl\OwlCal\Domain\Model\Event::getAttendees() must be an instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage, null returned
```

However, I have the attendee property initialized in the constructor. The following image shows the code and the xdebug break at the getter-call:
[image]

How is it, that the attendees property is `null`, while there should not be any way to set this property to a null value?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your getter return a null value instead of an ObjectStorage, you should change the method signature - something like that :

```
class Event extend AbstractEntity {
    protected $attendees = null;

    public function getAttendees(): ?ObjectStorage
    {
        return $this->attendees;
    }
}
```

But the question seems to be more about why the attendees is null I guess. To answer, we need more information : look at the getter, the constructor, the class.

Comment: No, that is not my problem. This case should never be able to pop up, because the property should not be nullable in the first place. The constructor sets a default value and the setter does not allow for setting null.

Comment: As I told you, without seing more code I can't give you more information on the problem. May be it's just a typo.
Did you set a breakpoint in the constructor and check if $this->attendees is well initialized ?